# Unable to decode unicode for Stack Exchange API

Tags: python, urllib

I was looking at [this codegolf problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127058/10-clickbaits-you-cant-resist), and decided to try taking the [python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127082/43537) and use `urllib` instead. I modified [some sample code](https://gist.github.com/kaito834/af2ad953e3f47a6fde42#file-urllib-request_json-py) for manipulating `json` with `urllib`:

```
import urllib.request
import json

res = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=hot&site=codegolf')
res_body = res.read()

j = json.loads(res_body.decode("utf-8"))
```

This gives:

```
➜  codegolf python clickbait.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clickbait.py", line 7, in <module>
    j = json.loads(res_body.decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

If you go to: http://api.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=hot&site=codegolf and click under "Headers" it says `charset=utf-8`. Why is it giving me these weird results with `urlopen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res_body` is gzipped. I'm not sure that uncompressing the response is something `urllib` takes care of by default.

You'll have your data if you uncompress the response from the API server.

```
import urllib.request
import zlib
import json

with urllib.request.urlopen(
    'http://api.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=hot&site=codegolf'
    ) as res:

    decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(res.read(), 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    j = json.loads(decompressed_data, encoding='utf-8')

    print(j)
```